# Slaughtering an Animal

Tags: sharia, dhabihah

Peace 
I want to know what the rightest way to slaughter an animal is. There are different methodologies of slaughtering an animal, but what is the most authentic way to slaughter any animal they way Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) used to slaughter an animal.
Want to ask in more specific what the rightest way to slaughter the following animals is

1. Goat
2. Cow
3. Camel

If authentic references are added that would be more thank full
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Islam , there are conditions for animals slaughtered to be addressed .
Decapitating the animal has five conditions :

1. The person who beheads the animal (either male or female ) must be Muslim .
2. Beheading have to be done by something from Iron and it must be very shrap.
3. In the time of beheading, in front of the animal's body has to be faced Mecca and Qibla.
4. When He wants to cut the animal's head, or when put a knife to his throat , should have take the name of god for beheading intentions, and this much to say: "Bismillah " is enough.
5. The Halal meat term is that slaughtered animal before beheading  should be alive, hence It is said that After decapitating the animal's movements have to be seen (although , for example, moving the  eyes or his tail or hits his feet on the ground ), which is known to have been alive.

There is a Hadith from Imam Muhammad Baqir:

> Do the Slaughtering by kindly and non violence, and do not behead any animal in fron of other animals and never sharpening the knife in front of the animal's eyes and even do not tell the animals bad words.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter which religion is the performer as long as the conditions are fulfilled which is the animal must be slaughtered by the sharpness of the knife or the instrument not by pressure and that goes for sheep and goats and cows the performer must cut the arteries and the wind pipes not the whole head until the animal left dead and bloodless these are the conditions and the Muslims could eats the Jewish slaughtered animals.

*NOTE: camels could not be slaughtered, the method called Nah'r which is producing a hole in the front of the neck and the cows could go either way.*